# How to get a bitmap from a scan in Apple Notes

Tags: pdf, notes.app, scanning

I love the scanning capability of Apple Notes, it does a great job of squaring up the images, and the black and white seems to have a good adaptive thresholding algorithm.

But, I can't find any way to export the scans as a **bitmap** image (PNG, JPEG) — it always comes out as PDF. This is true on both iOS and MacOS. Is there something I'm missing?